# How to enable IntelliSense on LitElements in a .svelte file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte, intellisense, web-component, lit

Using [LitElements](https://lit.dev/) (extension of Web Components) in **Svelte** is a breeze :

```js
// MyView.svelte
<script>
  import '@lit-elements-random-lib/my-lit-element'
</script>

<div>
  <my-lit-element>Hello, World !</my-lit-element>
</div>
```

However `my-lit-element` comes with its own custom props, and I couldn't find a way to make IntelliSense's auto-completion work in this case in VSCode. Please note I have already installed the [official Svelte extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode).

Is this a feature that needs to be implemented, or am I missing some configuration to make IntelliSense work here ?

I tried various VSCode extensions, however none of them seemed to enable auto-completion on the LitElements props in my Svelte files.

Answer (score 2):

For VS Code you have two options for this:

#### Option 1: `html.customData`

In your VS Code settings JSON you can enhance the HTML intellisense with custom data. This mostly makes sense when the library you use already provides such data; example:

```json
{
  "html.customData": ["./node_modules/@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/vscode.html-custom-data.json"]
}
```

You can read more about the custom data format in [this blog post](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/02/24/custom-data-format)

#### Option 2 (probably better): Add custom typings

`html.customData` helps you with auto completion and hover info but it won't error on wrong values. To have this, you need to enhance Svelte's DOM typings (which works similar to how you would enhance JSX typings). This can be done by placing code like this in a `.d.ts` file within your project:

```
// enhanced-typings.d.ts
declare namespace svelteHTML {
    // enhance elements
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        'my-lit-element': {
            somerequiredattribute: string;
            someoptionalattribute?: boolean | undefined;
            'on:event': (e: CustomEvent<any>) => void
        };
    }
}
```

You can read more about enhancing typings in [Svelte's language tools docs](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like to avoid to duplicate the interface description if possible. Is there any way to map the props from the class `MyLitElement` directly to the interface in `enhanced-typings.d.ts` file ?